# Outputting depth of current node in the hierarchy

Tags: xslt, xpath

Using XSLT/XPATH 1.0, I want to create HTML where the `class` attribute of a `span` element indicates the depth in the original XML hierarchy.

For example, with this XML fragment:

```
<text>
    <div type="Book" n="3">
        <div type="Chapter" n="6">
            <div type="Verse" n="12">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</text>
```

I want this HTML:

```
<span class="level1">Book 3</span>
<span class="level2">Chapter 6</span>
<span class="level3">Verse 12</span>
```

How deep these `div` elements could go is not known a priori. The `div`s could be Book -> Chapter. They could be Volume -> Book -> Chapter -> Paragraph -> Line.

I cannot rely on the values of @type. Some or all could be NULLs.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**This has a very simple and short solution -- no recursion, no parameters, no `xsl:element`, no `xsl:attribute`:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="div">
  <span class="level{count(ancestor::*)}">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(@type, ' ', @n)"/>
  </span>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<text>
    <div type="Book" n="3">
        <div type="Chapter" n="6">
            <div type="Verse" n="12"></div></div></div>
</text>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<span class="level1">Book 3</span>
<span class="level2">Chapter 6</span>
<span class="level3">Verse 12</span>
```

**Explanation**: Proper use of templates, AVT and the `count()` function.

Answer (score 6):

Or without using recursion - but Dimitre's answer is better than my one

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/text">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//div">
    <xsl:variable name="depth" select="count(ancestor::*)"/>
    <xsl:if test="$depth > 0">
        <xsl:element name="span">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('level',$depth)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(@type, ' ' , @n)"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

As usually with XSL, use recursion.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/text">
    <html>
      <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:with-param name="level" select="1"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="div">
    <xsl:param name="level"/>

    <span class="{concat('level',$level)}"><xsl:value-of select="@type"/> <xsl:value-of select="@n"/></span>

    <xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level+1"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```